How to remove history of commits of last 18?
I was trying to commit code to my project while testing a loop, Now I don't want my team member to see that I have commited code many times the project in the last 2 hours without adding value to my code:
The last 18 commits (except the last one so its the 17 commits before the last one)  were useless. So I want to remove them and keep the last one. That is I want to first and foremost remove the git history of the commits of those mentioned.
How to do that?
I saw that an interactive rebase could help in this case, but what is the exact command to use?

This is called a rebase or squash

could you tell us the exact command to use?

Making a commit to git should never be considered a "deployment".  That the word "deployed" is used to describe a push to a remote repo is a clear sign of the decline of our industry.  Rome is collapsing.  The empire is in disrepair.

Please look for existing questions. Here’s one that encompasses what you are asking: Preferred Github workflow for updating a pull request after code review. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+last+commits

@sam You have a fundamental flaw in your perspective.  If you stop thinking of a push as a deployment, then your problem literally goes away.  The fundamental flaw in your process is that you do not have a proper deployment procedure, which you need.  Precisely because it protects you from the problem you are currently experiencing.

Two suggestions:

Your teammates shouldn't mind that you are testing your code. That's a normal part of software development. Just be honest about it and they will understand :)
If you want to clean up the history in your local branch, use git history re-writing. After you rewrite your local branch, you can "force push" your branch to your remote repository to update it to remove your commits from there too.

